# For printing results of a google search, Beautiful Soup is giving none, though value is present

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, google-search

I want to write a python code which will take a query as an input from the user and print the Us in the google search of that query for first 20 pages.

My code is the following:

```
print("Google Search")
from googlesearch import search                                  
import requests
import sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
import urllib.request 

word= input("Enter the word to be searched: ")

page='https://www.google.com/search?q='+word

for url in search(word):
    response = requests.get(page)
    soup=BS(response.text,'html.parser')
    a= soup.find('td',{'class':"cur"}).text.strip()
    if a==21:
       sys.exit()
    print(url)
```

## The full error text is:

```
soup.find('td',{'class':"cur"}).text.strip()

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Comment: What word did you use for the input?  that element might not be there depending on the search word.

Comment: @CalebGoodman I entered the word "Hi" and <td class="cur"> is present in the navigation table for each and every google search.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same thing using selenium and it works.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

print("Google Search")
word= input("Enter the word to be searched: ")


driver_path = 'C:\Windows\chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path)
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
input_element = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
input_element.send_keys(word)
input_element.submit()


while(1):
    elems = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("TbwUpd")
    for elem in elems:
        b=elem.text.strip()
        print(b)

    num = driver.find_element_by_class_name('cur')
    a=num.text.strip()
    if a=="20":
        sys.exit()
    else:
        link = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Next").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

To handle `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'` you can use `try/except` block to handle this error. Possibly it's a wrong element you were trying to scrape. Or you can check `if` an element/class exists before proceeding to `for loop`.

Code and [example in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Scrape-Google-Search-Actual-Pagination-Python-SerpApi):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, urllib.parse
import lxml

def print_extracted_data_from_url(url):

    headers = {
        "User-Agent":
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
    }

    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'lxml')

    print(f'Current page: {int(soup.select_one(".YyVfkd").text)}')
    print(f'Current URL: {url}')
    print()

    for container in soup.findAll('div', class_='tF2Cxc'):
        head_text = container.find('h3', class_='LC20lb DKV0Md').text
        head_sum = container.find('div', class_='IsZvec').text
        head_link = container.a['href']
        print(head_text)
        print(head_sum)
        print(head_link)
        print()

    return soup.select_one('a#pnnext')


def scrape():
    next_page_node = print_extracted_data_from_url(
        'https://www.google.com/search?hl=en-US&q=coca cola')

    while next_page_node is not None:
        next_page_url = urllib.parse.urljoin('https://www.google.com', next_page_node['href'])

        next_page_node = print_extracted_data_from_url(next_page_url)


scrape()
```

Part of the output:

```
Results via beautifulsoup

Current page: 1
Current URL: https://www.google.com/search?hl=en-US&q=coca cola

The Coca-Cola Company: Refresh the World. Make a Difference
We are here to refresh the world and make a difference. Learn more about the Coca-Cola Company, our brands, and how we strive to do business the right way​.‎Careers · ‎Contact Us · ‎Jobs at Coca-Cola · ‎Coca-Cola System
https://www.coca-colacompany.com/home

...

Current page: 6
Current URL: https://www.google.com/search?q=coca+cola&hl=en-US&ei=IZ3VYIeQHY38tAX1pojwDQ&start=50&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwjHpIDnt7LxAhUNPq0KHXUTAt44KBDw0wN6BAgBEEg

Coca-Cola | Category | Fox Business
The Coca-Cola Company is a multinational beverage corporation best known for its flagship product Coca-Cola, invented in 1886 by pharmacist John Stith ...
https://www.foxbusiness.com/category/coca-cola
```

---

An alternative solution is to use [Google Search Engine Results API](https://serpapi.com/search-api) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free trial of 5,000 searches. Check out the [playground](https://serpapi.com/playground) to test out.

Code to integrate:

```py
# Python package: https://pypi.org/project/google-search-results
from serpapi import GoogleSearch
import os

def scrape():
    params = {
        "engine": "google",
        "q": "coca cola",
        "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),
    }

    search = GoogleSearch(params)
    pages = search.pagination()

    for result in pages:
        print(f"Current page: {result['serpapi_pagination']['current']}\n")

        for organic_result in result["organic_results"]:
            print(f"Title: {organic_result['title']}\nLink: {organic_result['link']}\n")

scrape()
```

Part of the output:

```
Results from SerpApi

Current page: 1
Current URL: https://www.google.com/search?hl=en-US&q=coca cola

The Coca-Cola Company: Refresh the World. Make a Difference
We are here to refresh the world and make a difference. Learn more about the Coca-Cola Company, our brands, and how we strive to do business the right way​.‎Careers · ‎Contact Us · ‎Jobs at Coca-Cola · ‎Coca-Cola System
https://www.coca-colacompany.com/home

...

Current page: 6
Current URL: https://www.google.com/search?q=coca+cola&hl=en-US&ei=IZ3VYIeQHY38tAX1pojwDQ&start=50&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwjHpIDnt7LxAhUNPq0KHXUTAt44KBDw0wN6BAgBEEg

Coca-Cola | Category | Fox Business
The Coca-Cola Company is a multinational beverage corporation best known for its flagship product Coca-Cola, invented in 1886 by pharmacist John Stith ...
https://www.foxbusiness.com/category/coca-cola
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.